# Passing single quotes through query showing error

Tags: c#, sql

```
string query = "Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode='"+S"';";
```

The above query is showing an error as it is missing semi-colon.   `"';"`   How can I pass single quotes for this query?

Comment: You missed one `+`. It should be: `where itemlookupCode='"+S+"'`. Also this kind of string concatenation are open for SQL INJECTION. Try using parameters instead.

Comment: You want to escape the quote. string query = "SELECT * FROM getLabelDetails WHERE itemLookupCode=\"" + s + "\";";

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiles - you are missing the `+` between `S` and `"';"` - `itemlookupCode='" + S + "';";`

Comment: You're leaving your program wide open to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks if you format your SQL that way...

Comment: The code snippet you've provided would not compile. Furthermore, you're not giving any indication of what the error is or where you're seeing it. If you fix these problems, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Simple correction to your query is :

```
string query = "Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode='" + S +"'";
```

But it will cause [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), I prefer you to use [parameterized query](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) instead of this to avoid `SQL Injection`.

You can do like the following:

```
String sql = "Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode=@foo";
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here")) 
   {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) 
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@foo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Baz;
        //execute command here
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the single quote. Every one of your single quotes needs another single quote before it.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell, but I'm not sure if that's the problem in this case. If he were trying to use dynamic SQL then yes. However, if this is just a C# string that is being passed into a `SqlCommand`, then I do not think your answer applies.

Comment: I guess you might be right, but after all, this query is passed in SqlCommand which will be applied in the database so all rules should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need another quote. Try:

```
string query = "Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode='" + S +"'";
```

Since C# 6.0 you can also try String interpolation:

```
string query = $"Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode='{S}';";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var s = "something";
string query = "Select * from getLabelDetails where itemlookupCode=\'"+ s +"\';";
```

Comment: How do you planning to  handle `Sql Injection`

Comment: The question didn't ask about the best practice for performing queries in C#. It asked how to escape a variable in a string. And I find it entertaining how this answer gets a down vote for not addressing SQL injection, but not the other answer in this post  that lists the exact same answer.